# How to find the probability of an intersection of a complement?

Tags: probability

I have $P(A)=.6$, $P(B)=.4)$.

A and B are independent.

Calculate the probability of $P(A^CB)$, $P(A~union~B^C)$.

For the first one I thought I had to just multiply $(.4)(.4)$ but for the second one I do not know how to approach it. Would it be that: $= P(A) + P(B^C) - P(B^C|A)$? And $P(B^C|A) = \frac{P(B^C~intersection~A)}{P(A)}$? This had me in a loop?

Comment: You can't calculate these things without knowing if $A,B$ are dependent and, if so, how.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ independent events?

Comment: @drhab I'm hoping they are independent.

Comment: Hope is not enough. As @lulu said: without further info this cannot be solved. Further the expression that you give for $P(A\cup B^{\complement})$ is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:$$P(A\cup E)=P(A)+P(E)-P(A\cap E)$$

This can be applied on $E=B^{\complement}$.

If $A$ and $B$ are independent then also $A$ and $B^{\complement}$ are independent.